# Сложность сортировки вставками

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка

Википедия пишет что сложность сортировки вставками О(n2) (квадрат) в худшем случае. Дан худший случай - массив по убыванию: 321, нам нужен по возрастанию 123. Если учитывать только перестановки, то получаем:

321

```
2 вынул
3 сдвинул
2 вставил
```

231

```
1 вынул
3 сдвинул
2 сдвинул
1 вставил
```

Получили 123. Но действий произошло только 7, а должно быть 9 (3 в квадрате). Вроде ещё сравнения нужно учитывать. Добавим сравнения:

```
321
сравнить 2 и 3, 2 меньше - двигаем
2 вынул
3 сдвинул
2 вставил
```

231

```
сравнить 2 и 3, 2 меньше - ок не двигаем
сравнить 2 и 1, 1 меньше - двигаем
1 вынул
3 сдвинул
2 сдвинул
1 вставил
```

Действий стало уже 10, тогда сложность выходит О(n2 + 1). Я что-то не так считаю? Ошибка в википедии? или как посчитать правильно что бы было 9?

Comment: Понимаете, если даже действий будет 10000*n^2 - это все равно O(n^2). И если их в конкретном случае *может быть* n/2, но в общем - n^2 - то это O(n^2). И если, скажем, одних действий n^2, а других в том же алгоритме - 10000*n - то и это все равно O(n^2)...

Comment: То что среднее время меньше я понимаю, но всё же почему максимальное не 10000*n^2 + 1? Вот в чём вопрос

Comment: O(n^2) - это *обобщенная запись*, говорящая всего лишь о том, что начиная с какого-то (вероятно, очень большого) значения N отношение реального времени работы к N^2 не превысит какой-то неизвестной константы.

Comment: Поскольку записи `O(n^2)` и `O(10000*n^2+1)` обозначают абсолютно одно и то же, то традиционно используется та запись, которая короче.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`O`-нотация указывает форму зависимости - линейная, квадратичная, экспоненциальная, какая выйдет. И для нее совершенно безразличны +- трамвайные остановки - от того, что на `N` подействовали линейной функцией, результат не изменится.

Грубо говоря, O-нотация указывает на то, как выглядит на бумаге график в осях "число объектов" - "число операций". От того, что этот график двигают,  (прибавляя к `N` всякое), растягивают (домножая `N` на константу) его *форма* не поменяется.

Comment: Т.е. это указывает на то что примерно O(n^2) а мелочи просто не берутся в расчёт? Просто максималку могли бы уж ради математической точности написать правильно...

Comment: @fosh4455, речь идет не о _мелочах_, а о виде функциональной зависимости. Дополню ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Формально O-обозначения дают **асимптотическую верхнюю границу**, т.е. для данной функции `g(n)` обозначение `O(g(n))` означает *множество функций*

*O(g(n)) = { f(n): существуют положительные константы c и n<sub>0</sub> такие,

                  что 0<= f(n) <= cg(n) для всех n >= n<sub>0</sub> }*

Подробнее об O, Ω и Θ обозначениях см. [Кормен, Лейзерсон, Ривест, Штайн "Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ"](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1794-2.html)